# Create columns from grouped counts (involving datetime column)

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing experiments on mice.

A section of my df is below.

```
Index   Name    Time        Food    Experiment Start
0       Peter   09:00:00    Cheese  2018-08-06 07:30:00
1       Peter   10:00:00    Nut     2018-08-06 07:30:00
2       Peter   11:00:00    Nut     2018-08-06 07:30:00
3       Peter   12:00:00    Cheese  2018-08-06 07:30:00
4       Peter   13:00:00    Nut     2018-08-06 07:30:00
5       Peter   14:00:00    Nut     2018-08-06 07:30:00
6       Peter   15:00:00    Nut     2018-08-06 07:30:00
7       Peter   11:10:00    Nut     2018-08-12 10:30:00
8       Peter   12:10:00    Cheese  2018-08-12 10:30:00
9       Peter   13:10:00    Nut     2018-08-12 10:30:00
```

I want a df like this:

```
Index   Name    Experiment Start        Last Meal in Experiment
0       Peter   2018-08-06 07:30:00     2018-08-06 15:00:00
1       Peter   2018-08-12 10:30:00     2018-08-12 13:10:00
-not enough width-
Count Food  Count Nut   Count Cheese
7           5           2
3           2           1
```

To find the 'last meal in experiment', it's easy.
I sort by 'Time' (time of meal), so the latest times are always on the top.

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Time', ascending=False)
```

Then I keep only those top latest times, by removing all other duplicates of Name and Experiment Start times.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Experiment Start'])
```

I calculate the time the last meal like this:

```
df['Last Meal in Experiment'] = df['Experiment Start'].dt.floor('D') + df['Time']
```

Now I should have something like this (along with Time and Food columns):

```
Index   Name    Experiment Start        Last Meal in Experiment
0       Peter   2018-08-06 07:30:00     2018-08-06 15:00:00
1       Peter   2018-08-12 10:30:00     2018-08-12 13:10:00
```

**But I'm missing how to get the count of food, and count of cheese/nut by Name's Experiment Start Time.**

Before removing duplicates, I tried something like this:

```
df['Count Food'] = df.groupby('Name')['Experiment Start'].transform('count')
```

But pandas has a bug (new column is formatted as dt) and I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1= df.groupby(['Name','Experiment Start','Food']).size().unstack()
df1['All'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
```

Or [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab([df['Name'],df['Experiment Start']], df['Food'], margins=True)
```

---

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Time', ascending=False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Experiment Start'])
df['Last Meal in Experiment'] = df['Experiment Start'].dt.floor('D') + df['Time']

df = df.join(df1, on=['Name','Experiment Start'])
print (df)
        Name     Time Food    Experiment Start Last Meal in Experiment  \
Index                                                                    
6      Peter 15:00:00  Nut 2018-08-06 07:30:00     2018-08-06 15:00:00   
9      Peter 13:10:00  Nut 2018-08-12 10:30:00     2018-08-12 13:10:00   

       Cheese  Nut  Count  
Index                      
6           2    5      7  
9           1    2      3
```